# create a python daemon that accepts keywords and excecutes commands as root

Tags: python, c, linux, pi

OS = Ubuntu Server

I have no idea for the best way to do this and would appreciate any pointers.

I'm using an SBC (orange pi 5b) and PWM support is broken using wiringpi.
I can execute the following commands when logged in as root to create a 50Hz square wave on pin 2

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip5/export
echo 20000000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip5/pwm0/period
echo 1000000 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip5/pwm0/duty_cycle
echo 1 > /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip5/pwm0/enable
```

I cannot execute the same commands in a user account using sudo or change permissions for the pwmchip5 directory

What I would like to achieve is to create a daemon/service/api/rpc (preferably in Python but I have a little skill in c) that runs as root (using crontab on boot or as a service) and that any non-root user can send it commands like

```
pwmservice init pwmchip5
pwmservice period pwmchip5 20000000 
pwmservice duty_cycle pwmchip5 1000000 
pwmservice enable pwmchip5
```

without having to be root or using sudo. Note that these last 4 commands would get the service to execute the bash commands above as root

is this possible and could someone point me in the right direction. Also, would something like this work or is there a better way.

https://betterprogramming.pub/a-simple-way-to-make-rpcs-with-python-52ad8e9286c1

cheers

Comment: Can you at least set the setuid bit? `chmod ug+s rpc`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a Linux permissions question than a programming question, but nevertheless:

You could use `ls -l` to determine the group-owner of the files in `/sys/class/pwm/...`, for example, this might be group `gpio`. Then add all users who need to execute those commands to that group with `adduser username gpio`. Maybe you need [some udev rules to set up the group ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230947/gpio-for-raspberry-pi-gpio-group) first.

---

Or you could write a small C program for this, compile it, and then put the compiled binary in `/usr/local/bin/pwmcontrol` with SETGID to the `gpio` group, or whichever group owns the control files <sup>1</sup>. Then it will always run with the rights of that group. Note that SETGID (and SETUID) only works with a *compiled* program, not with a script.

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -pedantic pwmcontrol.c -o pwmcontrol
sudo cp pwmcontrol /usr/local/bin/
sudo chgrp gpio /usr/local/bin/pwmcontrol
sudo chmod g+s /usr/local/bin/pwmcontrol
```

Here's some C code to get you started, including error handling.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int pwm_enable() {
    /// TODO implement
    return 0; // success
}

int pwm_disable() {
    /// TODO implement
    return 0; // success
}


int write_file(const char *path, const char *data) {
    FILE *f = fopen(path, "w");
    if (!f) return 1;
    size_t length = strlen(data);
    size_t written = fwrite(data, 1, length, f);
    fclose(f);
    return (length != written) ? 1 : 0; // 0 == success, 1 == fail
}

int pwm_export() {
    /// TODO implement
    return 0; // success
}

void err_exit(const char *message, int exitcode) {
    perror(message);
    pwm_disable(); // for safety reasons, turn off PWM if something went wrong
    exit(exitcode);
}

int pwm_set(const char *period, const char *duty_cycle) {
    if (0 != write_file("/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip5/pwm0/period", period)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (0 != write_file("/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip5/pwm0/duty_cycle", duty_cycle)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; // success
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Determine what to do according to the first argument
    if (argc == 4 && strcmp(argv[1], "set") == 0) {
        if (0 != pwm_export()) {
            err_exit("Error exporting PWM chip", 1);
        }
        if (0 != pwm_set(argv[2], argv[2])) {
            err_exit("Error setting PWM period and duty cycle", 1);
        }
        if (0 != pwm_enable()) {
            err_exit("Error enabling PWM", 1);
        }
        exit (0); // 0 == success
    }
    else if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "start") == 0) {
        // TODO
        exit (0); // 0 == success
    }
    else if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "stop") == 0) {
        // TODO
        exit (0); // 0 == success
    }

    printf("Usage:\n");
    printf("    %s set PERIOD DUTYCYCLE\n", argv[0]);
    printf("    %s start\n", argv[0]);
    printf("    %s stop\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Of course, you could also use SETUID root (`chown root` + `chmod u+s`), but running something as root is dangerous. Especially if it is a C program that you wrote yourself without any idea of how C security exploits work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. tried adduser username gpio with no luck and setting udev rules as found on other sites but still no luck. Manged to get an RPC server installed as per the code below and it seems to work perfectly. Cheers again.

Comment: @DaraOh Did you check the group with `ls -l`? Is it really `gpio`? Running services as root mostly a bad idea from a security point of view.

Comment: I added the following udev rule

SUBSYSTEM=="pwm*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
        chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/pwm && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/pwm;\
        chown -R root:gpio /sys/devices/platform/soc/*.pwm/pwm/pwmchip* && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/platform/soc/*.pwm/pwm/pwmchip*\
'"
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules

I see that /sys/class/pwm is root:gpio but /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip* are all root:root 

I'm a bit out of my depth here but I would have thought that chown -R should have changed ownership of subfolders as well? Cheers for taking the time

Comment: @DaraOh: Looks okay on first glance. Did you reboot after adding those rules? Otherwise they are not executed. Also, does it work when you execute the `chown` and `chmod` commands manually (as root)?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Definitely rebooted a few times and manually running chown/chmod as root doesn't return an error but permissions are unchanged

Comment: Okay, if manually changing permissions does not work, then writing the same commands in a script will be no use. However, if you want to pursue that further, you should probably ask a new question about that, on unix.stackexchange.com for example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

install the python rpc library

```
pip install rpyc
```

log in as root and create the following server.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import rpyc
from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer


@rpyc.service
class GPIOService(rpyc.Service):
    def write_val(self, data: int, filename: str):
        """Run shell command

        Args:
            data (int): saved value
            filename (str): file to edit
        """
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            print(data, file=f)

    @rpyc.exposed
    def pwm(self, chip: int, period: int, duty_cycle: int) -> str:
        """Set PWM

        Args:
            pin (int): wiringpi pin number
            period (int): set period
            duty_cycle (int): set duty cycle

        Returns:
            str: _description_
        """
        assert isinstance(chip, int), "Chip no must be an int"
        assert isinstance(period, int), "Period must be an int"
        assert isinstance(duty_cycle, int), "Duty Cycle must be an int"

        # init
        try:
            self.write_val(0, f"/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip{chip}/export")
        except:
            print("Initialization failed, may already be initialised")
        # PWM params
        self.write_val(period, f"/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip{chip}/pwm0/period")
        self.write_val(duty_cycle, f"/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip{chip}/pwm0/duty_cycle")
        # enable
        self.write_val(1, f"/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip{chip}/pwm0/enable")

        return f"Success: {chip=} {period=} {duty_cycle=}"

    @rpyc.exposed
    def pwmdisable(self, chip: int) -> str:
        assert isinstance(chip, int), "Chip no must be an int"
        # disable PWM
        self.write_val(0, f"/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip{chip}/pwm0/enable")

        return "Success"


print("starting PWM server")
server = ThreadedServer(GPIOService, port=18811)
server.start()
```

This can be automatically started at boot and as root using crontab

Then use the following snippet as the regular non root user

```
import rpyc

connection = rpyc.connect("localhost", 18811)
print(connection.root.pwm(4, 20000000, 5000000))
```

This creates a 50Hz where the pwm arguments are (pwm_chip_no, period, duty_cycle)

​

Comment: No need to call bash to write to a file. It can be done in plain python: `with open(filename, 'w') as f: print(data, file=f)`

Comment: Perfect. Cheers for that was initially using popen stdout to debug and lazily changed it to run. Above is more intuitive. I wonder which is faster?